# Different color for underline then font

Tags: css, text-decorations

Is there a way to make different color for underline of text then text itself?

It seems that `text-decoration-color` is [not available](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-color.asp) on most browsers. So is there other way?

Comment: Use a border? Use a pseudo element? Lots of ways. But you cant access the underline directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `border-bottom`, and `text-decoration: none`. It seems same as underlined link.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is a underlined link</a>
```

Hope this helps!